# Order of javascript execution in multiples widgets

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, sitefinity

I have 3 widgets in the same page in sitefinity. I need execute one by one the javascript in this widgets.

```
widget1
function1(){
   doSomething();
}
```

when function1 its done:

```
widget2
function2(){
   doSomething();
}
```

when function2 its done:

```
widget3
function3(){
   doSomething();
}
```

I tried global variables in master page to executing one by one but, does't work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you invoke function2 at the end of function1?

Example:

```
function1(){
   doSomething();
   function2();
}

function2(){
 doSomething2();
 function3();
}
```

Maybe if you give some more details we could help better.